# Change the strings value of Resource FIle in C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, resources, var

I have a resource file in my UWP C# Project, I know how to get the value of the string, but I don't know how to change this value, I put this code but it doesn't work.

```
        var resourceloader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
        var asd = resourceloader.setString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources are read-only in the running app. You will need to change the resource file and rebuild using it.

If you want to save a value persistently you can use the [ApplicationData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data) object s.

Comment: How I use the Application Data Objects?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data